# Screen. Turn on logging(like -L) by screenrc

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Which option in screenrc working like "screen -L"?
I want turn on logging globaly. Try option "log on" into /etc/screenrc, but write "log: window required" when screen startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `deflog on` instead of `log on`.

From the manpage:

```
 deflog on|off

   Same as the log command except that the default setting for new windows is changed. Initial setting is off.
```

If you really want to use `log on`, you need to first select a window with `screen 0`, but be aware this configuration does not configure logging for all windows...